# OpenGL compute shaders producing incorrect texture coordinates from invocation ID

Tags: opengl, glsl, depth, compute-shader

I have a compute shader that samples a depth sampler2D, however when using texture() the result is weird with some jagged edges. If I use texelFetch() then it works fine, so I would guess its an issue with getting the correct texture coordinates? FYI the sampler uses nearest filtering and has no mips.

This is how the result looks when using `texelFetch`:
[image: using texelFetch()]

And this is the result when using `texture`:
[image: Using texture()]

[image: glsl shader]

Comment: It still gives the same results as texture() at lod 0

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Please paste the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`texelFetch` expects integer coordinates of the texel; you provide these, they are exact, suffering from no rounding errors, thus you see no artifacts.

`texture*` family of functions expect floating-point coordinates, and then converts them back to texel coordinates by `floor(uv*size)` formula (this is assuming it's a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` with `GL_NEAREST` filters, which seems to be your case). This calculation is sensitive to floating point rounding errors when `uv` sits right between the texels, which is exactly what happens here.

To fix that, offset uv coordinates by half a pixel:

```
vec2 TexCoord = (vec2(iuv) + 0.5)/vec2(size);
```

Comment: Doesn't that only change the texture by a maximum of one pixel? In the image in the question, it seems that the result is different by way more than just one pixel around the texture border.

Comment: @BDL looks exactly like off-by-one pixel to me 

Comment: You are absolutely right. I missed that the two images have different sizes. Don't know why op thought that it's a good idea to provide different sized images.

Comment: no the images are all the same size, this worked for me btw

Comment: Strange. When I download the images, the first one is 910x742 while the second one is 795x631. @DarxDev

Comment: ye those are just screenshots, the actual images in the shader are all from the same framebuffer